# What is the optimal size for a boolean variable

Tags: c++, ios, boolean

I have come to believe that the optimal size for a boolean variable is the natural width of the data, ie in C/C++ it is int. So for modern processors this is normally 32 bits. At the machine level declaring it as a byte for example requires a 32 bit fetch and then a mask.

However I have seen that a BOOL in iOS is 8 bits. I had assumed that people who used bytes were using left-over ideas from 8 bit processors.

I realise this question depends on the use and for most of the time the language defined boolean is the best bet, but there are times when you need to define your own, such as when you are converting code arriving from an external source or you want to write cross platform code.

It is also significant that if a boolean value is going to be packed into a serial stream, for sending over a serial line such as ethernet or storing it may be optimal to pack the boolean in fewer bits. But I feel that it is likely that it is optimal to pack and unpack from a processor optimal size.

So my question is am I correct in thinking that the optimal size for a boolean on a 32bit processor is 32 bits and if so why does iOS use 8 bits.

Comment: Yes; the answer is "it depends"!

Comment: Most 16, 32 and 64-bit processors can read a byte just as quickly as a whole word; the masking happens in hardware without needing any extra clock cycles. Not all can, though, so it does indeed depend. And if that is the case, then making it larger can hurt performance, since you're wasting valuable cache space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of an 8-bit quantity involving a 32-bit fetch followed by hardware masking is *mostly* obsolete. In reality, a fetch from memory (on a modern processor) will normally be one L2 cache line (typically around 64-128 bytes). That being the case, essentially *every* size of item you deal with involves fetching a big chunk of data, and then using only some subset of what you fetched (but, assuming your data is more or less contiguous, probably using more of that data subsequently).

C++ *attempts* (not necessarily successfully) to optimize this a bit for you. An individual `bool` can be anywhere from one byte on up, though on most typical implementation, it's  either one byte or four bytes. The (much reviled) `std::vector<bool>` uses some tricks to give a (sort of) vector-like interface, but still store each `bool` in one bit. In the process it loses the ability to be treated as a generic sequence container -- but when you're storing a lot of bools, and can live with the restrictions of using it in an array-like manner, it can actually be a lot more useful than many people believe.

When/if you want to retain normal container semantics and don't mind the extra storage space to keep them their native size, you can use another container (e.g., `std::deque<bool>`) instead. Especially if you only need to store a small collection of `bool`s, this can often be a superior alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can fetch one byte _from_ L2 cache either. Somewhere between main memory and the eventual register the data requested is narrowed down to a single byte, but there's quite some room for implementation variations.

Answer (score 2):

Yup you are right it depends.  The big advantage of using an 8-bit is that you can pack more into a struct nicely.

Of course you'd be best off using flags in such a case.

The big issue, though, is that with a C/C++ "bool" you don't necessarily know how big it is.  This means that you can't make assumptions about a struct (such as binary writing to disk) without the possibility of it breaking on another platform.  In such a case using a known sized variable can be very useful and you may as well use as little space as possible if you are going to dump the structure to disk.

Comment: So IF you are going to pack booleans in a struct the smaller size is optimal but otherwise int is optimal? Or if you are going to use classes that know how to serialise themselves rather than overlaying structs, int is optimal?

Comment: If you've a few `bool`'s to store, `std::bitset` can be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

It is architecture dependent, but on many 32 bit architectures 8 bit addressing is no less efficient than 32 bit; the "fetching and masking" as such is performed in hardware logic.

The optimal size in terms of storage space is of course 1 bit.  You might for example use bit-fields or bit masking to pack multiple booleans in a single word.  Some architectures such as 8051 have bit addressable memory.  The more modern ARM Cortex-M architecture employs a technique called *[bit-banding](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Behcjiic.html)* that allows memory and hardware registers to be bit addressable